# How do I check when my next Airflow DAG run has been scheduled for a specific dag?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, airflow

I have airflow set up and running with some DAGs scheduled for once a day "0 0 * * *".

I want to check when is the next time a specific dag has been scheduled to run, but I can't see where I can do that within the admin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want you use the `Airflow`'s `CLI`, there's [`next_execution` option](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#next_execution)

> Get the next execution datetime of a DAG.
>
> ```
> airflow next_execution [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] dag_id
> ```

---

**UPDATE-1**

If you need to do it programmatically (within an Airflow `task`), you can refer to

- [`next_execution(..)` function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py#L602) of [`cli.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/bin/cli.py)
- (now moved to [`dag_next_execution(..)` function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c1f94786b901b8e5dabc963514062f7dda878aae/airflow/cli/commands/dag_command.py#L269) of [`dag_command.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c1f94786b901b8e5dabc963514062f7dda878aae/airflow/cli/commands/dag_command.py) in [`master`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/cli/commands/dag_command.py))

> ```
> @cli_utils.action_logging
> def next_execution(args):
>     """
>     Returns the next execution datetime of a DAG at the command line.
>     >>> airflow next_execution tutorial
>     2018-08-31 10:38:00
>     """
>     dag = get_dag(args)
>
>     if dag.is_paused:
>         print("[INFO] Please be reminded this DAG is PAUSED now.")
>
>     if dag.latest_execution_date:
>         next_execution_dttm = dag.following_schedule(dag.latest_execution_date)
>
>         if next_execution_dttm is None:
>             print("[WARN] No following schedule can be found. " +
>                   "This DAG may have schedule interval '@once' or `None`.")
>
>         print(next_execution_dttm)
>     else:
>         print("[WARN] Only applicable when there is execution record found for the DAG.")
>         print(None)
> ```

---

**UPDATE-2**

To get not just the next, but further `execution_date`s, refer to [Airflow - how to get all the future run date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63527204/3679900)

Answer (score 9):

In version 2.0.0 of airflow, on the command-line you can find the next execution [with](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#next-execution)

```
airflow dags next-execution <dag_id>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to fetch this within airflow you can use the jinja `{{ next_execution_date }}` but if you just wanted to find out when your dag will run next you can add the interval with the last run

For example

from the below image

[image]

Schedule interval is 15 minutes and last run was at 2018-09-07 08:32 so next run will be exactly 15 mins later which is 2018-09-07 08:47

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see that programmatically (tested with Airflow v2.2.4):

```
info = dag.next_dagrun_info(None)
info.run_after  # datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 9, 22, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))
```

you can also have:

```
info.logical_date  # datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 8, 22, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))
info.data_interval  # DataInterval(start=datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 8, 22, ...
```