# Problem with Airflow DAG and its schedule

Tags: airflow

I am having issues with a DAG created, I am trying to create a DAG to run weekly on Mondays.

This is the current setting of the DAG:

```
dag = DAG(
        "NAME_OF_THE_DAG",
        description="description",
        default_args=default_args,
        start_date="Fri, 01 May 2020 00:00:00 GMT",
        end_date=None,
        schedule_interval="30 3 * * 1",
        catchup=True,
    )
```

The DAG runs the first task on the first Monday of the May (4th of May 2020), but then is not executing the following week.

Does anyone what could be? I thought it was something with qeued tasks, but after cleaning the tasks, the scheduled didn't triggered the expected next execution.

Comment: Did you check when is the [next run scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52214602/3679900)?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow schedules each task at the *end* of each interval. So your runs will be...

- Monday, May 3 @ 3:30 will execute on Monday, May 10 @ 3:30
- Monday, May 10 @ 3:30 will execute on Monday, May 17 @ 3:30
- Monday, May 17 @ 3:30 will execute on Monday, May 24 @ 3:30

etc.

Why is this? Since Airflow is a tool built for data workflows where each task operates on a slice of time, and the data for a slice of time is not ready until that slice of time has ended. So for instance with your schedule, you define a window for May 3 to May 10, and that data won't be ready until May 10.

I've found pages 11-14 of this PDF to do the best job of explaining: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVN4HXtOC-HXvv00sEkoB90mxLDnCIKc/view