# Airflow - how to get all the future run date

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am working on scheduling a airflow job. However to verify if I have scheduled the correct job I need to see when it will run in the future.

Airflow has following command which gives me the next run. however, that's not sufficient for some use cases. for example, I have scheduled a job run every other Friday. How do I verify that.

```
airflow next_execution <dag_id>
```

Is there a way, I can get all the future dates when this dag will run. or atleast couple of ?

Answer (score 5):

While *most* processes use `croniter`, if you have access to your installation it's always best to get the information from the "source" via existing interfaces:

```py
from airflow import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


dag_bag = models.DagBag()

dag_id = "dag_name"
dag = dag_bag.get_dag(dag_id)

now = datetime.now()
until = now + timedelta(days=21)

runs = dag.get_run_dates(start_date=now, end_date=until)
print(runs)
```

Comment: I am getting the exception when I run on the dag. 
`from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
ImportError: No module named sshtunnel`

Comment: How do you mean "run on the dag" ? From the looks of the error you're missing a package.

Comment: Package is. Available.. I am. Able to trigger dag manually

Comment: No it's not? Wherever the execution is happening, your installation is unable to find `sshtunnel` -- create a new question with the trace and details for assitance.

Comment: `[root@server airflow]# pip freeze | grep -i sshtunnel
sshtunnel==0.1.5`

Comment: Okay... now go convince Python of that -- wherever your process is running is unable to import that module. Are the permissions correct? Ownership?

Answer (score 1):

Airflow uses under the hook croniter, for an [example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.6/_modules/airflow/models/dag.html#DAG.get_run_dates). Following the example on the documentation of [croniter](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/), this could work as follows (as example, consider that the dag run at 12 pm every Friday and that our base date is yesterday the 20th of August).

```
from croniter import croniter 
from datetime import datetime

# Specify current date
base = datetime(2020, 8, 20, 0, 0)

# Set croniter
iter = croniter('0 12 * * 5', base)  

# Get next execution 
iter.get_next(datetime)
>>>
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 21, 12, 0)
```

where you can specify `base` as the latest execution date of your dag (`dag.latest_execution_date`). And you can get it's following executions by calling n times `iter.get_next(datetime)`.